# Is hell permanent?

Tags: death

When someone dies, if they are destined for hell, do they stay there for all eternity, or will they eventually be freed from hell?

If they will eventually be freed, what happens then? Furthermore, do all people stay there for the same amount of time? How long?

Comment: I don't think there's a concept of TIME in the other world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When someone dies, if they are destined for hell, do they stay there for all eternity?

The disbelievers will stay in hell forever, and they will be punished however much God wills.

> or will they eventually be freed from hell?

**But**,  those people who have the smallest amount, like an atom or a small mustard seed, of faith/belief, then they will be let out of the hell fire.

> If they will eventually be freed, what happens then?

They are let into paradise. I hope the following Hadith clarifies that question...

> *Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "When the people of Paradise have entered Paradise, and the people of the Fire have entered the Fire, Allah will say. 'Take out (of the Fire) whoever has got faith equal to a mustard seed in his heart.' They will come out, and by that time they would have burnt and became like coal, and then they will be thrown into the river of Al-Hayyat (life) and they will spring up just as a seed grows on the bank of a rainwater stream." The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Don't you see that the germinating seed comes out yellow and twisted?"*  [Source](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/81/149).

---

> Do all people stay there for the same amount of time?

I am assuming that you are referring to those who stay in hell.  As for how long, I can say as long as God wishes (Or, there is a deduced belief that they'll be burnt until they're [re-payed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/23302/11938) for their bad deeds. But, the measurement of compensation is again in the hands of God, so God's wish).

Comment: There are also verses saying that [they will abide within eternally](http://quran.com/2/39), how do I understand it?

Comment: @mezhang that verse is referring to those who disbelieved and lied.

Comment: I believe I've edited to answer it thoroughly... Plz feel free to revert if you're not satisfied with the edit made.

Answer (score 1):

Bismillahi arrahmani arrahim

There is a huge debate about that.

A prevalent opinion is that Hell is not eternal as allah says in sourat nahl:

الآية: 37 ( يريدون أن يخرجوا من النار وما هم بخارجين منها ولهم عذاب مقيم )

which means that those who are in hell will not be able to leave by themselves (kharijin) which does not exclude the possibility of them being put out by God Almighty.

and when QUran says mokhrajine in the passive form it is subordinate to a precise time:

فاليوم لا يخرجون منها ولا هم يستعتبون (sourat AL Jathia)

which means that Today (and allah knows what is the scale of a day by that time) you will not be taken out from it (hell).

On the other hand when Quran talks about Heaven. It says:

وما هم منها بمخرجين (sourat alhhijr)

which means that those in paradise will not have to fear being put out from it (no definite time is precised which means undefinitely)

There are other arguments to back this claim. Explained with much depth in this sermon in Arabic:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=focDJVOtXoE

Allah knows best